# Text in itemize goes onto margin and doesnt align with other text

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I'm having some problems with margins.

```
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, headsep=0.4cm, bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=5mm}
```

When I use `itemize`, the text doesn't align with other text but goes into the right margin.

```
\begin{itemize}[align=right]
\item Friðrík H. Jónsson og Sigurður J. Grétarsson (2007). \textit{Gagnfræðikver      fyrir háskólanema}, Háskólaútgáfan, Reykjavík.
\item Ingibjörg Axelsdóttir og Þórunn Blöndal (2006).  \textit{Handbók um ritun og  frágang},  Mál og menning, Reykjavík.
\end{itemize}
```

Here is my output:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix the text in itemize? I'm using `scrbook` class.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Plus we cannot see which hyphenation pattern you are using, basically it does not know how to hyphenate `háskólanema`

Comment: as @daleif says, you need hyphenation patterns than can handle icelandic.

Comment: You could try to insert the instruction `\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}` in your document's preamble; hopefully this'll let LaTeX find appropriate hyphenation points for `háskólanema`...

Answer (score 2):

If you load `icelandic` and `babel` your Icelandic words will hyphenate according to the rule of the language.

Since the main language seems to be English, you can mix the two languages.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic,english]{babel} % default language is English

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, headsep=0.4cm, bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=5mm}

\usepackage{newtxtext} % Times font

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just to provide a paragraph giving context

\begin{document}
\kant*[1]
\begin{itemize}[align=right]

\item \begin{otherlanguage*}{icelandic}
  Friðrík H. Jónsson og Sigurður J. Grétarsson (2007). \textit{Gagnfræðikver fyrir 
  háskólanema}, Háskólaútgáfan, Reykjavík.
  \end{otherlanguage*}

\item \begin{otherlanguage*}{icelandic}
  Ingibjörg Axelsdóttir og Þórunn Blöndal (2006).  \textit{Handbók um ritun og 
  frágang}, Mál og menning, Reykjavík.
  \end{otherlanguage*}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]